# formatting .dscribe() output in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

descirbe() output
the method I used is below

```
creditcardDF.describe().apply("{0:.5f}".format)
```

the error I got is:

```
unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__
```

can someone explain to me what is the problem?

I also have another question

could anyone explain to me

`pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.5f' % x)`
**lambda x: '%.5f' % x** what's this mean?

and

`.apply("{0:.5f}".format)`
**"{0:.5f}".format** what's this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a `Series` (list like) to `str.format` method because Python doesn't understand how it should process this list.

```
>>> "{0:.5f}".format([1.23456789, 9.87654321])
...
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__


>>> "{0:.5f}".format(1.23456789)
'1.23457'
```

So you have to use `applymap` instead of `apply` to transform each individual values (which is not the best choice):

```
>>> df
          0        1         2
0  10.05856  9.31342  10.92815
1  15.32752  1.88274   5.79967
2  15.73966  3.19805   3.81324
3   9.02629  2.80339   0.77310
4  14.95545  4.84119   8.68670

>>> df.applymap("{0:.2f}".format)
       0     1      2
0  10.06  9.31  10.93
1  15.33  1.88   5.80
2  15.74  3.20   3.81
3   9.03  2.80   0.77
4  14.96  4.84   8.69
```

You can also override the default Pandas behavior using `pd.set_option` or `pd.context_option` (for temporary modification):

```
>>> print(df.describe())
             0       1        2
count  5.00000 5.00000  5.00000
mean  13.02149 4.40776  6.00017
std    3.20886 2.94391  3.98897
min    9.02629 1.88274  0.77310
25%   10.05856 2.80339  3.81324
50%   14.95545 3.19805  5.79967
75%   15.32752 4.84119  8.68670
max   15.73966 9.31342 10.92815

>>> with pd.option_context('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x):
        print(df.describe())
          0    1     2
count  5.00 5.00  5.00
mean  13.02 4.41  6.00
std    3.21 2.94  3.99
min    9.03 1.88  0.77
25%   10.06 2.80  3.81
50%   14.96 3.20  5.80
75%   15.33 4.84  8.69
max   15.74 9.31 10.93
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, Thank you very much for answering my question. I just want to format that specific outcome alone, doesn't want my entire notebook to be formated. I heard that <pd.option_context> can format entire notebook. is it the case if I used your last answer?

Comment: No. using `with pd.option_context:` you change the options only for the current block. However, if you use `pd.set_option`, the change will apply to your entire notebook. As you have only numeric columns after `describe()`, you can also use `df.describe().round(2)`